# How to add overlay to background image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am certainly new to Web design.

[image: Overlay]

As seen in this picture, most of the websites I see have this kind of mask over images, and then text over that mask.

So how do I achieve that if I don't edit the picture that way, and want to add the mask over it.

I am using a Bootstrap Jumbotron for the header part of website, with container-fluid property and it's height set at 100vh. 
I use an image as background image to the jumbotron. It's really a common thing and can be seen in many websites. For example: 
[image: Banner]

So how do I add a mask or an overlay to the background image, certainly a black tint, so that I can make white text visible.

P.S.
I am very new to css, and I came to know about these mask and overlay properties today itself.

Comment: You can certainly be helped with this issue, but you have to provide your code so that we may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest two blocks together, one with the background image, and the other with the overlay :

```css
.background{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56be46d2a3360cae707270a0/t/5772ef9b20099e38818859b0/1467150245253/');
  background-size: cover;
}

.overlay{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="overlay">
    <!-- Content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The opacity of the overlay can be modified with the last argument of the `rgba()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use linear gradient:

`background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../some-image.jpg");`

For more info check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: This answer was very helpful. Thanks